# Memory error after running pyBrain NFQ learner for a few minutes

Tags: python, python-2.7, out-of-memory, pybrain, reinforcement-learning

O.

Using reinforcement learning from pyBrain we are trying to solve a game.
We use NFQ and an ActionValueNetwork as controller.
We have our self-made task and are using the experiment setup from pyBrain to train.
Our agent is reset after every episode.

The way we see an episode is one run on a level.
Each episode we call experiment.doInteractions() until the level returns either failed or finished.
After that we do agent.learn() and agent.reset()

At first we thought this error was because of a memory overflow due to running one episode too long. We had a move maximum of 10.000 inserted when we first encountered the error. I lowered it to 50 now which makes the program run for more episodes but still gives the error.

This makes us believe that it is not the amount of moves that is the problem but a cumulative history being saved somewhere and overgrowing its allowed memory size.
We believed agent.reset() would clear all history from memory, is this not so?
Can we stop the history from being saved somewhere?

Or does anyone have other suggestions?

edit:
This is the exception trace.

```
Running level: Single box block. Try: 125
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapperSokoban.py", line 168, in <module>
    wrapperSokoban().run_Qlearning()
  File "wrapperSokoban.py", line 154, in run_Qlearning
    self.run_Qlearning_level() 
  File "wrapperSokoban.py", line 122, in run_Qlearning_level
    self.experiment.doInteractions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/rl/experiments/experiment.py", line 18, in doInteractions
    self._oneInteraction()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/rl/experiments/experiment.py", line 29, in _oneInteraction
    self.agent.giveReward(reward)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/rl/agents/logging.py", line 62, in giveReward
    self.history.addSample(self.lastobs, self.lastaction, self.lastreward)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/reinforcement.py", line 40, in addSample
    self.appendLinked(state, action, reward)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/dataset.py", line 216, in appendLinked
    self._appendUnlinked(l, args[i])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/dataset.py", line 196, in _appendUnlinked
    self._resize(label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/dataset.py", line 181, in _resize
    self.data[l] = self._resizeArray(self.data[l])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/dataset.py", line 188, in _resizeArray
    return resize(a, shape)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 864, in resize
    a = concatenate( (a,)*n_copies)
MemoryError
```